# stop event for multiple event registration for same element in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Suppose there are multiple event registrations on the same element.

If a certain condition matches then execute only one event and stop others. e.g. for below case if someone type "1" in input box only print "hello", otherwise print "hello world"(different line).

```js
$(document).on("click","#12",function(e){
  if($("#1").val() == 1){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();  // do something that will stop other regestraion to run
  }
  fun();
});

$("#12").on("click",function(e){     //third party js
  console.log("world");
});

function fun(){
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="1">
<button id="12" class="12">click</button>
```

**Is it even possible to achieve something like this?** If yes then how?
(I could not found anything on net or stackoverflow question similar like this)

Edit:- Way of event registration is different. I can't do registration the way third party does, as the third party js load after some click events and input box will come after that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: @RolandStarke thanks

Comment: You cannot guarantee that a 3rd party script will register a handler after yours, so by the time your handler is called, their script may have already run.

Comment: @JuanMendes so you are saying It is not possible to achieve what I want.(just conforming)

Comment: @yajiv I didn't say it was impossible :p See my answer for an explanation and disclaimer.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on("click","#12",function(e){
  if($("#1").val() == 1){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();;  // do something that will stop other regestraion to run
  }
  fun();
});

$(document).on("click","#12",function(e){     //third party js
  console.log("world");
});

function fun(){
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="1">
<button id="12" class="12">click</button>
```

Is this what you want?
Source: https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

**Note**

This doesn't work if the third party library runs their code first and that you likely can't change the style of delegation of the third party library which is required for this solution to work.

```js
$(document).on("click","#12",function(e){     //third party js
  console.log("world");
});


$(document).on("click","#12",function(e){
  if($("#1").val() == 1){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();;  // do something that will stop other regestraion to run
  }
  fun();
});


function fun(){
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="1">
<button id="12" class="12">click</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, but please see the question(edited). your answer will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [event capturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase). Events traverse into the Element from the document and bubble back up into the document and you can stop events then. If you're handling events on the default phase, your handlers will be called after if you can't make sure you register it first.

You can play with the feature [on this pen](https://codepen.io/jmendes/pen/VxJdjW) from that article

[image: event bubbling capturing]

**Disclaimer:** event capturing is a feature that should only be used by very low level code and should be used as a last resource if you're not working on something very generic which is not the case here. A real life case I have seen is for modals since it needs to completely block user input from outside the modal (not just hide it behind a DIV and let a user focus on something else with their keyboard).

[This page](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#capturing) has a nice example of the pitfalls of using `stopPropagation()` just above the capturing section; `stopImmediatePropagation()` is even worse because it also relies on order of event registration. Doing it in the capture phase has the potential to affect a lot of code, **be careful**.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#12", function(e) { //third party js
  console.log("world");
});

function captureHandler(e) {
  if (e.target.id != "12") return;

  if ($("#1").val() == 1) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  fun();
}
// Third parameter says use the capture phase
document.addEventListener('click', captureHandler, true);

function fun() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="1">
<button id="12" class="12">click</button>
```

And it obviously still works for the original case

```js
function captureHandler(e) {  
  if (e.target.id != "12") return;
   
  if ($("#1").val() == 1) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  fun();
}
document.addEventListener('click', captureHandler, true);

function fun() {
  console.log("hello");
}

$(document).on("click", "#12", function(e) { //third party js
  console.log("world");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="1">
<button id="12" class="12">click</button>
```